# XCode9.4.1 Swift: Showing image instead of text on map annotations

Tags: swift, dictionary, annotations

you know how the title and subtitle show up when you click on an annotation in MKMapView.
How can i show an Image/images instead of the subtitles text?
atm i am using:

```
class customPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
   var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
   var title: String?
   var subtitle: String?

   init(pinTitle: String, pinSubTitle: String,    
      Location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
      self.title = pinTitle
      self.subtitle = pinSubTitle
      self.coordinate = Location
   }
}
```

I tried replacing the "String" with "UIImage" (at the "Subtitle"´s) but that didnt work either

thanks for any help,
 Gus

Answer (score 0):

`MKAnnotation` only manages the data for the pin, not the appearance. The `MKAnnotationView` is the visual representation of the pin. You can manipulate and generate this using the `mapView(_:viewFor:)` method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "customPin"
    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView

    if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
        annotationView = dequeuedView
        annotationView.annotation = annotation
    } else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "example")
    }   

    return annotationView
}
```

See also: [Apple Developer Documentation on MKAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview)